# How to format table with awk printf?

Tags: bash, awk, format, printf

How to make print column perfectly align with formatted table?

```
  | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_,,,_"
    printf "%-10s | %-10s | %-10s \n", "Date", "Tag", "Name"  } ;
    {
    date=strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M",$2) ;
    printf "%-10s | %-10s | %-10s \n", date, $1, $3
    }' | column -t -s "|"
```

The firs proble was that column utterly misaligned and the reason for the misalignment is lengths of words in column are very different. So For a quick-and-dirty fix, I pipe it through column, Is there way to create table with this setup?

This is the output of the code

```
Date                 Tag                           Name
2020-11-11  06:12    foo                           foo
2020-11-11  06:12    bar                           something-with-a-longer-name
2020-11-11  06:12    something-with-a-longer-name  bar
```

Expected output

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________
| Date                | Tag                          | Name                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2020-11-11  06:12   | foo                          | foo                          |
| 2020-11-11  06:12   | bar                          | something-with-a-longer-name |
| 2020-11-11  06:12   | something-with-a-longer-name | bar                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This really sounds like a waste of time. Why don't you just convert the input to CSV/TSV and open it with Excel?

Comment: What's wrong with using `column -t` ?

Comment: This is doable in awk but you have to calculate the length of all the lines before printing each column and the horizontal lines.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the input file that you'd want to produced that output from. We can't test a potential solution with just the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for many OSs):

```bash
mlr --itsvlite --ifs '_,,,_' --hi --opprint --barred put '                                                                                
    $* = {
        "Date": strftime($2,"%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M"),
        "Tag": $1,
        "Name": $3
    }
' input_file
```

With an input file like yours:

```
foo_,,,_1605075121_,,,_foo
bar_,,,_1605075122_,,,_something-with-a-long-name
something-with-a-longer-name_,,,_1605075123_,,,_bar
```

That will output:

```
+-------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
| Date              | Tag                          | Name                       |
+-------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2020-11-11  06:12 | foo                          | foo                        |
| 2020-11-11  06:12 | bar                          | something-with-a-long-name |
| 2020-11-11  06:12 | something-with-a-longer-name | bar                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: have you fully fixed that arbitrary code execution security hole in `Miller` ? I was a wee bit concerned how a convenience app designed as a drop in replacement/enhancement for select  `Unix / POSIX` text manipulation utilities ended up with something as severe as potential arbitrary code execution by nefarious actors.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto The one exploiting `.mlrrc`? It was fixed a few years ago